# What does se.fit represent exactly? How can we compute it manually?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, predict, standard-error

Given the following code in R why should we have an array of standard errors instead of one standard error?

```
library(dplyr)
library(HistData)
data("GaltonFamilies")
set.seed(1983) 

 galton_heights <- GaltonFamilies %>% 
      filter(gender == "male") %>% 
      group_by(family) %>%
      sample_n(1) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      select(father, childHeight) %>% 
      rename(son = childHeight)
```

Now consider this:

```
fit <- galton_heights %>% lm(son ~ father, data = .)
Y_hat <- predict(fit, se.fit = TRUE)
```

The predicted values could be extracted by this code:

```
Y_hat$fit
```

which gives us the predicted height of Sons for the fathers in galton_heights.

However, I do not understand why do we have an array of standard errors when we run this code:

```
 Y_hat$se.fit
```

What do these values refer to? and how could they be calculated manually?

Comment: See the answers there: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/486547/11849